# Get a list of blog entries with a postdate within the last 24 hours using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

Anyone know how to format a XSL so that I get a list of blog entries with a postdate within the last 24 hours? I tried using a combo of currentdate and <= but couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

There are a range of Umbraco extensions available for handling dates in XSLT. As Michael notes below, Umbraco uses XSLT 1.0 (which is what .Net supports), which doesn't have much to offer for working with dates.
One which might interest you is: DateGreaterThanOrEqual. I'm not sure whether it deals with DateTime, if not you could use:

`umbraco.library:DateDiff($now, $then, 'm')` to get an integer value in minutes, and test if it's less than/equal to 1440.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/datediff

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that current-date() is an XSLT 2.0 function but Umbraco only supports XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco has its own CurrentDate() method in XSLT.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/currentdate